# Local valet wordpress site redirects to real site

Tags: wordpress, laravel-valet

I used to use MAMP to locally host my wordpress website and it worked fine.

I recently started doing Laravel development so I use homebrew and valet. (which apparently interfered with MAMP because it stopped working, I'm still new to that whole area, so now I have to use wordpress with valet)

I was able to connect to my website using `mysite.dev` and I could see the homepage but without any date because the database was empty. Then I imported my database and now when I use `mysite.dev` in any broswer, it redirects me to `www.mysite.ca` (the actual website and not the local one).

I did do the command `valet park` in my wordpress repository.

How can I possibly fix this ? I suspect it's some setting in wordpress but I can't even access my local wp-admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try adding the following to your wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mysite.dev');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysite.dev');
```

This forces WordPress to recognize your current domain.

Comment: I would also indicate that you have to clear your browser's cache! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer, it resolved my issue.